# How to print the partial text from an element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get the text "Album Vol.1 [Every letter I sent you] LP (Normal Edition)" from http://www.ktown4u.com/iteminfo?grp_no=231307&goods_no=44363#dt_wrap01 under the description tab but I keep getting this error message.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@class='view_body']/div[2]/span"}
```

Different variations give me similar error messages.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.view_body>div:nth-child(2)>span')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='view_body']/div[2]/span")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('span')
```

I've also tried `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

With this xpath:

```
'//div[@id="contents"]/div/div/div[2]/span'
```

Test in dev tools:

```
$x('//div[@id="contents"]/div/div/div[2]/span')[0].textContent
"Album Vol.1 [Every letter I sent you] LP (Normal Edition)"
```

Comment: Terminal gives me - selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id="contents"]/div/div/div[2]/span"}

Comment: Which driver ? Tested OK with firefox and brave (chromium) browser

Comment: I am using chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

To print the text **Album Vol.1 [Every letter I sent you] LP (Normal Edition)** you you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('http://www.ktown4u.com/iteminfo?grp_no=231307&goods_no=44363#dt_wrap03')
  print(re.split('[*\-]',WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.payment-order-list>ul>li"))).text)[1])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('http://www.ktown4u.com/iteminfo?grp_no=231307&goods_no=44363#dt_wrap03')
  print(re.split('[*\-]',WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='payment-order-list']/ul/li"))).text)[1])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Album Vol.1 [Every letter I sent you] LP (Normal Edition)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Terminal gives me - selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.