# How to extract the text H MATTHEWS from the html using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, xpath-1.0

By using 'contains' function how can I extract information from this type of html structure, I am trying to **scrape** "H MATTHEWS" this information

HTML:

```
<p>
<strong>Date Published:</strong>
&nbsp; 20 APRIL 2020
<br>
<strong>Closing Date / Time:</strong>
&nbsp;TUESDAY, 05 MAY 2020
<br>
<strong>Enquiries:</strong>
<br>
Contact Person: H MATTHEWS
<br>
Email:&nbsp;
</p>
```

HTML image:

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: There's no way anyone can answer this question without knowing what the HTML actually *is*.

Comment: @MattDMo I am new in stackover flow, I am still trying to upload the html structure.

Comment: @MattDMo can u help me now 
<p>
<strong>Date Published:</strong>
&nbsp; 20 APRIL 2020
<br>
<strong>Closing Date / Time:</strong>
&nbsp;TUESDAY, 05 MAY 2020
<br>
<strong>Enquiries:</strong>
<br>
Contact Person: H MATTHEWS
<br>
Email:&nbsp;
</p>

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code you have tried so far, the output you're getting (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

The text ***Contact Person: H MATTHEWS*** is within a text node. So to printthe text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *childNodes*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[9].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[./strong[text()='Date Published:']]")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[./strong[text()='Date Published:']]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[-3])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

If your usecase is to extract only the text ***H MATTHEWS*** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `XPATH` and *childNodes*:

  ```
  print(re.split('[:]', driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[9].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[./strong[text()='Date Published:']]")))).strip())[1])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(re.split('[:]', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[./strong[text()='Date Published:']]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[-3])[1])
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [How to retrieve partial text from a text node using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445850/how-to-retrieve-partial-text-from-a-text-node-using-selenium-and-python/62446227#62446227)
- [How to print the partial text from an element using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408680/how-to-print-the-partial-text-from-an-element-using-selenium-and-python/62409183#62409183)