# How do I use selenium to scrape text from a text node within a class through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have some HTML that I am using selenium to scrape, I want to scrape the text inside the small tags. I cannot use XPath as for other examples, the XPath changes.
This is the HTML:

```
<h3 class="price">
    $28.04
<small>ex</small><br> <small>$30.84 <small>inc</small></small></h3>
```

I know you can use `price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price")` and using `price[1].text` to get the text but I end up getting a selenium webdriver element:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a95cede569123a83f5b043cd5e138c7c", element="a3cabc71-e3cf-4faa-8281-875f9e47d6a4")>
```

Is there a way to scrape the 30.84 text?

Comment: Can you post the url?

Comment: It's hard for me to post the URL because you need a login to access it. Is there any other info I can post?

Comment: gotcha, post the full error message

Comment: Seems I was mistaken, my output seems to somewhat work, I get the text:
$28.04 ex
$30.84 inc 
Do you know if there is a way to get the second price?
The output is a 20 character string so my solution would be to grab the last 10 characters of the string, but this would not work if the digits change.

Comment: Try this `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='price']//small(contains(., '$'))").text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text ***30.84*** is within a text node. So to print the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *childNodes*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='price']//small[.//small[text()='inc']]")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='price']//small[.//small[text()='inc']]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [How to retrieve partial text from a text node using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445850/how-to-retrieve-partial-text-from-a-text-node-using-selenium-and-python/62446227#62446227)
- [How to print the partial text from an element using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408680/how-to-print-the-partial-text-from-an-element-using-selenium-and-python/62409183#62409183)