# The result of the xpath expression "html/body/div/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element error printing element text using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I'm attempting to extract "479" from this sample HTML:

```
<div data-testid="testid">
  "479"
  " Miles Away"
</div>
```

I'm using the following Selenium code in Python:

```
xpath = 'html/body/div/text()[1]'
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
distance = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
print(distance)
```

Which returns the following error:

```
'The result of the xpath expression "html/body/div/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.'
```

I've attempted to remove `text()[1]` from the end of my xpath, theoretically printing off all data contained the in the HTML div, but it will instead print a blank line when I do so.

Note: I'm an amateur and self-taught (via mostly Google, YouTube, and this site), so some of my wordage may not be correct. I apologize in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the html:

```
<div data-testid="testid">
  "479"
  " Miles Away"
</div>
```

Both the texts *`479`* and *`Miles Away`* are with in 2 different [text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007124/7429447).

Selenium doesn't supports *`text()`* as it returns a text node, where as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) expects back a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447). Hence you see the error:

```
The result of the xpath expression "html/body/div/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

---

### Solution

To extract the text **479** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* through `execute_script()` and *textContent*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='testid']")))).strip())
  ```
- Using *xpath* through `splitlines()` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='testid']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[1])
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't treat text like that, the text() function returns everything as a string including a line break. I think there is no split function that can help you with that, I advise you to get the text in a python variable and do a split('\n') to the text.

```py
xpath = 'html/body/div/text()'
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
distance = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
print(distance.split('\n')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take the entire element (without text()) using only

```
html/body/div
```

then from returned element get text, which will be: "479" " Miles Away" .
Then using split method from python you can take that number(split by \n, space, or ").

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't support the following xpath
`xpath = 'html/body/div/text()[1]'`

To identify the element uniquely, Your xpath should be like

```
xpath = '//div[@data-testid="testid"]'
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
distance = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).text
print(distance)
```

To get the text of the element you have to use `element.text`