# robot framework / Selenium don't recognize xpath element text() and chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, robotframework

fellows!

I'm trying to get a the text which is recognized in the developer tool of chrome, but once I run the test in Robot Framework I'm getting an error.
The code used is:

`${name}=    Get Text  xpath://tr[1]/td[1]/text()`

[Chrome dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aK3m.png)

[Robot Framework result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijl3J.png)

As a work around I did this:

```
    ${obj_name}=            Get Text  xpath://tr[1]/td[1]
    ${obj_name_fd}=         Get Text  xpath://tr[1]/td[1]/mat-icon
    ${obj_name}=            Replace String   ${obj_name}   ${obj_name_fd}   ${EMPTY}
```

I did get "**xpath://tr[1]/td[1]**" which returns all the text in it:
"**auto_async_blah_blah_blah**".

Tha tag "**td/**" contains the tag "**mat-icon/**" with the text "**file_download**"  and also the pure text  "**auto_async_blah_blah_blah**" (without a tag... as [img][2]).
So as a result I have:

"file_download auto_async_blah_blah_blah"

Then I get the "xpath://tr[1]/td[1]/mat-icon" and replace it for ${EMPTY}, in order to keep only "**auto_async_blah_blah_blah**".

Answer (score 0):

This [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

```
//tr[1]/td[1]/text()
```

would return a [*TextNode*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75490257/7429447) where as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) expects back a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70203974/7429447).

---

### Solution

Modify your command as:

```
${name}=    Get Text  xpath://tr[1]/td[1]
```

Comment: Hi, friend, thanks for your answer!
I did get "xpath://tr[1]/td[1]" as a work around, but it returns all the text conteined in "//tr/td".
Tha tag "td/" contains the tag "mat-icon" with the text "file_download" and also the pure text  "auto_async_blah_blah_blah" (without tag).
So I have "file_download auto_async_blah_blah_blah"
Then I get the "xpath://tr[1]/td[1]/mat-icon" and replace it for ${EMPTY}, in order to keep just the "auto_async_blah_blah_blah".

Comment: @ChristianReSa So Selenium now recognizes the xpath element without `text()`. Glad to be able to help you. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.