# How can I access the 4th child text of an element which has arrays of texts via Selenium?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to access this text in the picture. I am using VB.NET and I need to show me in a MessageBox.
The sentence is: "My friend is going to watch a film in cinema but there is no tickets.".
When I right click on this and get the full Xpath, it shows me this:

```
/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/text()[4]
```

So this is the code I use in VB.NET:

```
MsgBox(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/text()[4]")))
```

But I get following error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: The
> result of the xpath expression
> "/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/text()[4]"
> is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

[image]

Comment: Your XPath ends with `/text()`. And the error says `The result of the xpath ... is: [object Text]. It should be an element.` What part of that does not make sense?

Comment: @SiKing I need to have the sentence in the msgbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
MsgBox(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML"))
```

It will retrieve whole texts.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div1/div/div/div[9]/div/div1/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr1/td[4]/div1/text()[4]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

...implies that the [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

```
/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div[1]/text()[4]
```

returned an `[**[object Text]**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75490257/7429447) which isn't supported by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447). Where as Selenium expects a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70203974/7429447).

---

### Solution

To extract the text from the 4th *Text Node* and show in a MessageBox you need to use the *`ExecuteScript()`* method as follows:

```
MsgBox((string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;" driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@class='yX Yx' and @role='gridcell']/div")))
```